Header file in Replit
did anyone using replit, I currently trying some program in Replit, but I need It in format of header file, I tried to change it into ".h" but doesn't work. I also tried to search It on YouTube but didn't find any.
I want to connect my CPP file with a header file in Replitc

Seems like it's not complicated https://ask.replit.com/t/how-can-i-make-header-file-in-c/62506
